# How can I get my FuelPHP application working in a subdirectory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, fuelphp

I have a FuelPHP application that I'm trying to setup to extend an existing website (we'll call it `example.com`). The FuelPHP installation is in a directory called `listings` within the `DocumentRoot`. However, the main `index.php` file for the application is located in a subdirectory of `listings` called `public`, so the actual path to the `index.php` file is `<DocumentRoot>/listings/public/index.php`. The static assets (JavaScript, CSS and images) for the application are in subdirectories of the `public` directory as well.

I want people to be able to access the application at `/properties`. Also, there will be requests made for other pages (such as `/properties/admin`) as well as requests for static assets (such as `/properties/assets/css/style.css`).

I've got this thing about 90% working. The `.htaccess` file in the `DocumentRoot` looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^properties/?(.*)$ /listings/public/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Inside the `public` directory, there is another `.htaccess` file that looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

# Send request via index.php (not if its a real file or folder)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I set the `$base_url` in the FuelPHP config to `http://example.com/properties/`. All of the URLs for the static assets are appearing the way I would expect them to, for example, the path to my `bootstrap.css` file appears as `http://example.com/properties/assets/css/bootstrap.css`. This is what I expect. However, instead of Apache grabbing the static asset, it's running the request though the FuelPHP `index.php` file, resulting in a 404.

I think I need to add a `RewriteCond` to the `.htaccess` file that is in the `DocumentRoot`, but I'm not exactly sure if that's correct, or what that `RewriteCond` would look like.

How do I adjust my `.htaccess` file(s) so that I'm able to access static assets such as `http://indyapm.com/properties/assets/css/bootstrap.css` which is actually located at `<DocumentRoot>/listings/public/assets/css/bootstrap.css`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is a RewriteBase

```
RewriteEngine On # after this
RewriteBase /properties/ # insert this
```

That, having your main config set up with the correct base url should do the trick.